# Can Droid 2 Global sync with Outlook 2010? Esp concerned with tasks

Tags: sync, outlook, exchange-tasks

Considering getting a Droid 2. I use Outlook for all calendar, contacts, and tasks. Although it is seamless for calendar items and contacts, task management is critical for me. I am not impressed with Google apps task mangagment and want to keep using Outlook. Is the Droid compatible with a sync directly to Outlook 2010? Under what conditions?

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the grand old man of the syncing world that Ryan's pointed out above, there's also [GOATS](http://www.gassumo.com/gassumo-outlook-android-tasks-synchronizer/how-it-works) and TouchDown as other notables.

There's a fairly detailed table at http://www.syncdroid.net/ that illustrates and lists software designed to sync data to Android devices.

Comment: Thank for the link to syncdroid- has a good chart for the various alternatives. I ended up using gsyncit- $19.99, with the gtask app for phone (free w/ ads, $3.99 without). Working pretty well so far. Keeping fingers crossed.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I know of for the level of syncing you want to achieve is [CompanionLink](http://www.companionlink.com/android/outlook/). It will sync Contacts, Calendar, Tasks and Notes between Outlook and Android, it will also cost you $49.95.

Comment: Thank you for the response. gsyncit coupled with gtasks app for droid seemed to be a good option, cheaper and with good reviews. Working pretty well so far.